# CMake py.test detection?

Tags: cmake, pytest

[py.test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html)  is know tool for testing Python scripts. I am missing, however, CMake macro for the detetion of py.test.

Is there anything of this kind within CMake pool of macros ?

Answer (score 3):

Directly calling `py.test` from a `CMakeLists.txt` isn't very portable, because different systems name it quite differently, e.g.:

```
py.test    # pip, as of early 2018
pytest     # ditto
py.test-3  # Fedora 26 package
pytest-3   # ditto
```

Of course, the system might default to version 2 or 3, and might have both version 2 and 3 installed side by side.

Thus, a simple method for reliable executing right pytest version via cmake is to [invoke pytest differently](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html):

```
python3 -m pytest
```

(instead of `py.test` or `pytest` or ...)

If you want to test in cmake if the pytest package is available you can test this with [`execute_process()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/execute_process.html), e.g.:

```
execute_process(COMMAND python3 -m pytest --version
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTEST_output
  ERROR_VARIABLE  PYTEST_error
  RESULT_VARIABLE PYTEST_result)
if(${PYTEST_result} UNEQUAL 0)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Pytest package not available: ${PYTEST_error}")
endif()
```